# Linear Regression using sklearn

Tags: regression, prediction, sklearn-pandas

I have a model fitted with data but having trouble using the predict function.

```
d = {'df_Size': [1, 3, 5, 8, 10, 15, 18], 'RAM': [3676, 6532, 9432, 13697, 16633, 23620, 27990]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df

X = np.array(df['df_Size']).reshape(-1, 1) 
y = np.array(df['RAM']).reshape(-1, 1) 
model = LinearRegression() 
model.fit(X, y) 
print(regr.score(X, y))

then when I try to predict on 

X_Size = 25
X_Size

prediction = model.predict(X_Size)
```

I get the following error

ValueError: Expected 2D array, got scalar array instead:
array=25.
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

I think I am passing the 25 in the wrong format but would just like some help on getting the response for Ram considering the 25 rows.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the predictor in the same shape (basically 1 column):

```
X.shape                                                                 
Out[11]: (7, 1)
```

You can do:

```
model.predict(np.array(25).reshape(1,1))
```